# Unwanted expansion on element

Tags: html, css

I am just getting into html and css, I am trying to set up a basic website with some features. I have gotten the nav bar to work mostly how I want it to, however I can't seem to have not expand downwards when I mouse over the projects part.

I have tried a few different ways of implementing it along with changing some css attributes but I am stuck. I want the drop down menu to overlap anything underneath and not expand the entire nav bar downwards.

Here is my html and css code respectively

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65, 1);
  
    margin:0;

    color:rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.dropbtn>a { /*added*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
</style>
<head>
    <style>
    
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_style.css">
    <title>example</title>
</head>

<h1>This is heading 1</h1>



<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            
                <button style="background-color: #333; padding:0" class="dropbtn"><a href="/projects">Projects</a> </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="images/test.jpg">image #1</a>
                    </div>
            
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"><a href="/die">Menu Title</a></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="images/test.jpg">image #1</a>
            <a href="images/favicon.ico">image #2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
    <h3>This is heading 3</h3>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

    <a href="images/test.jpg">This is a link</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Edit 1: I have updated my html in an online validator which has not fixed the error, and has caused one of the elements to start clipping into another. Below is the updated html.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65, 1);
  
    margin:0;

    color:rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.dropbtn>a { /*added*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
    
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_style.css">
    <title>example</title>
</head>





<body>

<h1>This is heading 1</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            
                <a style="background-color: #333; padding: 14px 16px" class="dropbtn" href="/projects">Projects</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="images/test.jpg">image #1</a>
                    </div>
            
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn" href="/die">Menu Title</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="images/test.jpg">image #1</a>
            <a href="images/favicon.ico">image #2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    
    <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
    <h3>This is heading 3</h3>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

    <a href="images/test.jpg">This is a link</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid. Use online HTML validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the position property in CSS and set the z-index property to control the stacking order of elements.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php